# Combining http servlets with other TCP server in Java

Tags: java, http, servlets, tcp, integration

Is it possible to have a Java application listen to HTTP requests via servlets and to listen to other TCP port at the same time? Is there a standard way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this, is to embed Jetty into your main application. Here is a [tutorial](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty).

With the embedded Jetty servlet container you can run standard Java web applications (WARs). At the same time in your main application you can listen to other TCP ports via a [ServerSocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html).